# Apply style to a specific element does not work with Safari

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, safari

I am trying to apply the below CSS to a specific element on the HTML page, it works perfectly on Chrome; however, in Safari it does not.

**CSS:**

```
  #customNav > .toolbar-background {
  background: none;
  border:0;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<ion-navbar id="customNav" *navbar>
 <div class="toolbar-background"></div>
</ion-navbar>
```

Anyone knows how I can make it work for Safari too?

Comment: Just done an edit, please check it out

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't work? Could you provide a reproducible jsFiddle?

Comment: There's an option called "Stack Snippets" which is similar to JSFiddle. Can you please press `Ctrl + M` and reproduce the issue here? Thanks. `:)`

Answer (score 0):

I've tested your code on Chrome and Safari. Contrary to what happened for you, it worked for me on both browsers. For the most part, things should be the same across all browsers.

But that's not the point. `<ion-navbar>` is not a proper HTML tag. I think the right tag that you are looking for is  (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_nav.asp).

And *navbar is also improper code. Could you let me know what that is for?